# filtering elements with two select elements with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

im struggling with two select elements to sort my squares and circles.

each select element work separately, but it doesn't work together.
can anyone tell me how can i make it work right?

please help!

```js
function colorType(){
  var colorBox = document.querySelector('#selectColor');
  var boxValue = colorBox.options[colorBox.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var blue = document.querySelectorAll('.card.blue');
  var red = document.querySelectorAll('.card.red');


  if(boxValue == 'blue'){
    for (var i = 0; i < red.length; i++){
      red[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < blue.length; i++){
      blue[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }
  
  if(boxValue == 'red'){
    for (var i = 0; i < blue.length; i++){
      blue[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < red.length; i++){
      red[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }  
}

function shapeType(){
  var shapeBox = document.querySelector('#selectShape');
  var boxValue = shapeBox.options[shapeBox.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var round = document.querySelectorAll('.card.round');
  var square = document.querySelectorAll('.card.square');

  if(boxValue == 'round'){
    for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++){
      square[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < round.length; i++){
      round[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }
  
  if(boxValue == 'square'){
    for (var i = 0; i < round.length; i++){
      round[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++){
      square[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.card{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.round{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hidden{
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<label>Choose the color 
  <select id="selectColor" onchange="colorType();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>Choose the shape
  <select id="selectShape" onchange="shapeType();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="round">Round</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
  </select>
</label>


<div class="card-holder">
  <div class="card blue round"></div>
  <div class="card blue square"></div>
  <div class="card blue round"></div>
  <div class="card red round"></div>
  <div class="card red square"></div>
  <div class="card blue square"></div>
  <div class="card red round"></div>
  <div class="card red square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got this error when running your code snippet:                                                         
     "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: shapeValue is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 85,
  "colno": 31                                                                                                              
  looks like you never declared shapeValue

Comment: yeah i made some experiments before i didnt note it. try now. :)

Comment: I'll give you a hint on how to solve this. When one drop down changes, you need to see if the other drop down has a specific value in it as well and then change your display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following, selecting cards, turn the `HTMLCollection` to Array and use `filter`.
The `display` function is quite useless but I let it so I didn't have to change the HTML.

#### EDIT : Detailed explanation

1. **You need to get all the cards.**

To do so, it's better to use `getElementdByClassName` since it returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).
`querySelectorAll` on the other hand returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).
 `HTMLCollection` are live collections while that's not always the case for `NodeList`.

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated
> when the underlying document is changed.

So once you get the card in your variable, if you add or remove cards, you don't need to update your variable value, it will be done automatically.

2. **Trigger your function when the inputs are selected**

You already did it, that's just the [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event.

3. **Get *shape* and *color* value**

Just retrieve your `select`s items with `document.getElementById` (faster thant `querySelector`), then the `value` attribute give you the value of the selected `option` inside your `select` tag.

4. **Display all your cards and hide the right ones**

Since `cards` is an HTMLCollection, you can't use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods on it, so you need to turn it into an array with `Array.from`.
Then you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and remove the 'hidden' class.

To add, remove or check the existence of classes, we use the [ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.
To filter the `Array.from(cards)`, use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, and then you can add the 'hidden' class to the desired cards.

```js
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

var colorSelect = document.getElementById('selectColor');
var shapeSelect = document.getElementById('selectShape');

function colorType() {
  display(colorSelect.value, shapeSelect.value);
}

function shapeType() {
  display(colorSelect.value, shapeSelect.value);
}

function display(color, shape) {
  Array.from(cards).forEach(card => card.classList.remove('hidden'));

  if (color) {
    Array.from(cards)
      .filter(card => !card.classList.contains(color))
      .forEach(card => card.classList.add('hidden'))
  }
  
  if (shape) {
      Array.from(cards)
      .filter(card => !card.classList.contains(shape))
      .forEach(card => card.classList.add('hidden'))
  }
}
```

```css
.card{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.round{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hidden{
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<label>Choose the color 
  <select id="selectColor" onchange="colorType();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>Choose the shape
  <select id="selectShape" onchange="shapeType();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="round">Round</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
  </select>
</label>


<div class="card-holder">
  <div class="card blue round"></div>
  <div class="card blue square"></div>
  <div class="card blue round"></div>
  <div class="card red round"></div>
  <div class="card red square"></div>
  <div class="card blue square"></div>
  <div class="card red round"></div>
  <div class="card red square"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: oh my god... thank you so much... i was struggling whole week to figure it out. 
i was thinking about converting it in to the array but didn't exactly know  how does it work. so now im gonna study your code. thank you again my friend! :D

Comment: I'll edit the answer to give more detailed explanation this evening

Comment: Hi @TomFoxtrot if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.